# Wrapping bare URLs in <sub>/<sup> tags breaks hyperlinks in the generated HTML (not in the preview)

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

I just edited [Common elements comparison between 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842) to add some links from the comments to related questions in a "see also" section - specifically, these links:

[In Python, how do I find common words from two lists while preserving word order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264471/)

[Python -Intersection of multiple lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852780/)

[Intersection of two lists including duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645053/)

In the post preview, they appear linked, showing the title of the corresponding Stack Overflow question and linking to them when clicked.

However, in the published version of the page, I am only seeing the raw URLs in plain text.

What happened? This has always worked before as far as I can recall, and I have used it this way many times.

---

I asked this in the Meta chat room at the same time, and it appears that there is some kind of conflict between this URL rendering and the raw HTML rendering. I am using the `<sub>` tag to reduce the text size; apparently, this causes a problem *if the URL is the only thing inside that tag*. Thanks to Cody Gray for the investigation and another edit to add some detail inside the `<sub>` tags.

---

##### Repro cases:

<sub>**See also:**</sub>

<sub>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264471/</sub>

<sub>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852780/</sub>

<sub>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645053/</sub>

<sub>https://example.com</sub>

<sup>https://example.com</sup>

Comment: @Lino Cody edited the title to mention both; I didn't actually test it myself, but I would be rather surprised if it only affected one and not the other.

Comment: From further experimentation, it seems that there must be something on *either side* of the URL; but "something" can be just a single space.

Comment: Supplemental to this: when trying to put a bulleted list inside sub or sup tags, it appears that an empty line is needed between the tags and the list on either side of the list. Otherwise, the closing tag will be "eaten"; if the next paragraph is also within such tags, it will then become even smaller. Currently demonstrated (in the fixed version) at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254 . This time, however, the behaviour is the same between the preview and submitted posts.